# Preappend timestamp in shell script which has embedded redirection

Tags: shell, unix

I have a unix shell script like below. I wanted to preappend a timestamp in front of every line of out.log. The general solution was create another script preappend.sh and execute the script like this:

```
(./a.sh 2>&1 ) | ./b.sh > out.log
```

However the original shell script has a line `exec 2>out.log`  (I have commented this out below for my testing earlier).  In real life this line is not commented. Could someone teach me how I would preappend the timestamp in out.log when there is a `exec 2>` in place?

benny

```
------ my script a.sh ---------
#!/bin/sh

#exec 2>out.log
set -x

echo 'hello world'
sleep 2
echo 'you rocks'
------end---------

---- preappend.sh ---
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
    echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'): ${line}"
done
-------end------------
```

Comment: If I replace the `exec 2> out.log` with this.   It will work.                          exec 2> >(while read line ; do echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'): ${line}"; done > out.log)     However is there a way not to edit the a.sh?

Answer (score 0):

Does this address the problem:

```
origScript.sh 2>&1 | awk '{ printf strftime() " " $0 "\n" }'
```

We can do a small test to check if this is working -

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  date
  (>&2 echo "error")
  sleep 1
done 2>&1 | awk '{ printf strftime() " " $0 "\n" }'
```

It returns something like this:

```
Tue Sep 20 19:11:43 UTC 2016 Tue Sep 20 19:11:43 UTC 2016
Tue Sep 20 19:11:43 UTC 2016 error
Tue Sep 20 19:11:44 UTC 2016 Tue Sep 20 19:11:44 UTC 2016
Tue Sep 20 19:11:44 UTC 2016 error
...
```